# Approach to handling update date update columns in ADF pipelines

Tags: azure, factory

New to Adf and trying to build a solution to handle the below simple scenario:

- Source and sink are both Azure sql db

New rows based on unique id are inserted with a null [update date] column
Any changes to existing rows have the [update date] column updated to current date

Would the copy data activity be enough to cater for the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Upsert** in the Copy activity. **Upsert** means update if exists and insert if not exists based on a column.


Follow below repro for your reference:


**My source table in SQL:**


[image]


**Target table:**


[image]


**Select upsert in sink:**


select Upsert, then you can give your **Unique Id** column in the **Key columns**.
The Upsert action will be done based on this column.

[image]


**Target table after execution:**


You can see that the existing rows are updated, and new rows are inserted.


[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail here RakeshGovindula. I should have mentioned that there are some dynamic fields im including like rowupdatedate which are not part of source as a source query. Would it still be possible to use the data copy activity in this case ?

Comment: select distinct 
       ACCT_ID as BKAccountId
      ,ACCT_NAME as AccountName
      ,cast(case when ACCT_ID like '52%' then 1 else 0 end as bit) as IsUnallowable
      ,cast(null as datetime) as RowUpdateDate
  from db.schema.table

Comment: Provide this query in the source of copy activity and select upsert in the sink. But make sure the schema that you get from this query is same as schema of your sink table.